# Unable to flash stm32f103c8t6 after erasure, device shows 0 bytes flash size (custom bootloader)

Tags: stm32, programming, flash, bootloader, firmware

I have flashed a dfu bootloader from https://github.com/davidgfnet/stm32-dfu-bootloader onto
a fresh stm32f103c8t6 and it was working fine. After I uploaded my binary with dfu-util
the device would no longer show up in usb dmesg so it seems like the bootloader was erased, although the program (a simple blinker) always ran for a few seconds after powerup and then stopped.

The problem is that from now on if I connect the device via stlink it reports a correct size of sram but 0 bytes of flash. I tried flashing with st-flash --flash=64k write ... but it didn't work. Only other thing that comes to mind is to do some kind of a reset so I tried st-flash --flash=64k erase, it looked like it worked but the device still reports 0 bytes flash memory.

What could be the cause of this? Did the bootloader remove some stm firmware required for flashing the chip? How come only flash size is reported as 0 but not sram? Is there a way to reflash the required firmware or is it bricked? I'm lucky to have bought two but still I'd like to rescue the first one if possible.

Comment: You can't remove ST firmware. What is the state of readout protection?

Comment: That part does not have a dfu bootloader, the application supported a bootloader, once you overwrote it with yours it was game over.  Now you need to use uart or swd or other, but not usb...

Comment: @old_timer the asker is explicitly describing results from a tool which uses SWD and *only* SWD

Comment: @ChrisStratton "so it seems like the bootloader was erased" sounds like a question, the answer is yes the dfu bootloader is an application not part of the st firmware

Comment: Again the asker is explicitly describing attempts to communicate via SWD, not a bootloader.

Comment: as to the problem put the part in the st bootloader and then try again with stlink.  or just use openocd and reprogram it

Comment: the wording is a little ambiguous in the first paragraph I refer to the bootloader as the dfu bootloader i provided a link for. In the last paragraph the bootloader refers to what I think (not sure) is on the stock device flashed by ST, that allows for SWD programming

Comment: No, the bootloader has nothing to do with SWD, which is a hardware not software part of the chip.  The one place the bootloader can be relevant for SWD is to prevent bad user code from running and turning the SWD into GPIO, but that would cause a complete SWD failure not what you have here. I forget if this is how a locked chip behaves, but look up how to do an unlock erase and then a full power cycle disconnecting every last wire to the board so none donate microamps to retain state.

Comment: The chip is part of a popular blue pill board so I'm unsure how would I do that. Should I desolder it and bridge all pins?